# Sharing the same FrameworkElement and DrawingVisuals instance across various Grids (WPF .net 4 )

Tags: wpf, drawing

I am doing an application where I draw using PathFigure, LineSegment, ... stored as DrawingVisuals in a FrameworkElement.

I need to show the same drawing in 2 different UI elements (Grids or Panels, whatever...) 
One will be used by the user to draw and the second will just allow to visualize the same drawing, zoom and scroll without affecting the 1st UI element viewport.

I will have more than 2000 DrawingVisuals, it would be stupid to duplicate them...

I am currently scratching my head to figure out the best way to do it.
What is, in your opinion, the right solution to achieve this?

More information:

I have tried the obvious way, with a simple XAML

```
<Grid>
<StackPanel>
   <Border Name="B1" Background="Bisque" Width="400" Height="200"/>
   <Border Name="B2" Background="Beige" Width="400" Height="200"/>
 </StackPanel>
</Grid>
```

Then a simple code

```
var map = new VdMap();
B1.Child = map;

var elem = new ElementVisual(map);
elem.StartElement(20, 20);
elem.AddSegment(80, 60);
elem.AddSegment(10, 80);
elem.EndElement();
elem.Draw();

B2.Child = map;
```

VdMap is a FrameworkElement

ElementVisual, StartElement, AddElement are my internal functions. The important thing are:

```
B1.Child = map; //I attach my Map to the border
B2.Child = map; //I try to attach the same FrameworkElement to the second border.
```

And I get the run time error "Specified element is already the logical child of another element. Disconnect it first."

Well looks like it is going to be harder than I thought.

Answer (score 0):

Ok,

I probably found the right way to do it: The VisualBrush and a Rectangle.

```
  var mapClone = new VisualBrush { Visual = map };

    rectangle = new Rectangle { 
         Width = 300, Height = 300, 
         Stroke = Brushes.Black, HorizontalAlignment = HorizontalAlignment.Left, 
         Fill = mapClone };

    B2.Children.Add(rectangle);
```

I have now in B2 a visual copy of my map that I can scale and transform separately.

Any better idea is welcomed.